How can a project manager create a plan without having specifications for the product defined at the beginning of the project?
In handling my first real project as a project manager, I need to create a project plan to produce a particular product. However, the specifications are not being defined up front.
As a part of the project plan the stakeholders will produce the actual specifications of the product. My question then becomes how do I create an accurate work breakdown structure or project schedule for the implementation of the specifications and the project overall without knowing what those specifications will be?
Gathering specifications is a significant part of the project. It wouldn't make sense to plan the rest of the project until the specifications are completed. Either way the stakeholders will not be pleased.

Do you know the dev team or is this selected later? Because you could look at earlier projects to maybe extract some info about progress. -- Generally: It is an estimate at first of course. Has to be refined throughout the dev process multiple times, probably weekly or so. The less you update and also fail to make apparent that the final date will shift from the first estimate, the worse of an PM you will be regarded as by devs and hated for it ;) My experience.

You should maybe ask yourself: Were you hired for being the PM or being the scapegoat for the stakeholders... Because you can also go bold and say: I am the PM, responsible for the project plan. You are the stakeholders, responsible for defining what you want, you have to deliver first. Then manage them until the requirements are defined. End of discussion. Everything else does not make sense for a "real project". It makes totally sense for some gridlocked processes that the stakeholders are used to and you are forced/considered to adapt to. That does not seem to be healthy in the long run.

The project obviously has some defined goal, even if how you get there isn't well-defined. Just make figuring out the path to the goal part of the project if there's no appetite or organizational ability to do that as part of project initiation. Just make the issue visible and transparent so that the risks of known-unknowns don't come as a surprise to anyone.


How does a project manager manage planning without the specifications of the product at the beginning of the project

With difficulties.
Without knowing the specifications, you need to make assumptions about things. Projects go sideways even when you do have specifications, so this will be extra challenging. You need to draft a rough outline based on what you know right now.
So, take everything you know and try to lay it down. To that, add the things that are not specific to the project but are needed to be setup (not sure the project type you have but in IT for ex, that can be provisioning equipment, installing servers, etc.). Add everything you think is needed.
You will need buffers (you don’t know what you don’t know). You are at the start of the cone of uncertainty. So, unless you find a way to squeeze in a "project discovery and definition stage" to try to find out more of what you are building before starting the project, you will need to rely on a lot of buffers.

Then do the estimate with your team. Do you have a team at this point? If not, more buffer. Then also add a project management overhead required to keep things under control (like 10% or overhead metrics already available within your organization).
Use a PERT estimation. Discard the optimistic value and present a range between the most likely and pessimistic values as your estimate. Be transparent that a lot of assumption went into it and even that can go wrong.
The best approach though would be an incremental one. Take the large cone of uncertainty and break it down into smaller ones.

This reduces risk and allows for discovery of what is needed as things progress. It also avoids building what you were asked to build (eventually), but then everybody complaining that it’s not what they wanted.
An incremental approach though is more difficult to pull over in an environment where everybody wants traditional project management where they don’t know what they want, but they know exactly when they want it... and it has to be cheap.
Good luck!

An amazing answer thank you very much

There are a few options.
One option would be rolling-wave planning. Perhaps some aspects of the project, such as the end date, are known and can be laid out. You may be able to plan enough work to gather requirements and specifications, validate those requirements and specifications, and then plan the remainder of the work, while capturing any other high-level milestones that may be otherwise fixed.
You could also take an even more adaptive approach and focus on control. If you know some characteristics of the project and what knowledge and skills you may need, you can build a team and work in short increments. If you have an understanding of how long it may take to get enough detail in a specification to start to execute, you can plan that portion of the effort and then revisit, perhaps even deciding that, based on the specification, it doesn't make sense to proceed.

One key Issue that's frustrating is how impatient the stakeholders are it makes me want to tear my hair out I feel like if I do a rolling wave plan the idea of waiting till all the requirements for every feature are ready before we start development will cause serious conflict. I'm thinking I have to somehow start developing each feature when the requirements are validated for that feature but then that approach makes my head hurt because it doesn't accommodate itself to long term project planning, it's similar to what you said in your second paragraph, so how would it look like if implemented

@OshokeSule Without knowing what type of project you have, it's hard to say. You could always start with the PMBOK and look up "adaptive" and "agile" and go from there to see what product management would look like. But without more information and more specific questions, it's hard to give a reasonable answer.

Also I would add, you are the PM supposed to report to some upper level. If you are not convinced of the projects plan because of the risk of "underestimating" the final requirements by a lot, then add maybe a margin of "times pi" (I learned that today :D) to a worst case scenario with the disclaimer that this is also just an estimate. Be transparent to the upper level and also to the stakeholders and also to the Devs. But try to still uphold a positive attitude towards the success of the project. If you do not believe in it and really want it to happen, nobody will. Is my advise.

Oh and just keep in mind: The death of most of the projects are requirements that need to be changed later, because it was rushed at the beginning. Nobody wants that to happen. So emphasis the first phase, even if you feel pressured by the stakeholders. Tell them, they are risking a failed project. Holding against the pressure and be convinced the plan will work out (that is the plan you worked out, so you need to be convinced in your own work) is the tough part of being the PM, I am afraid.

As you surmised, you cannot create an accurate work breakdown structure or project schedule for the implementation of the specifications and the project overall without knowing what the specifications are.
What you can do is some clever guestimating by talking to the developers who will be implementing the product.
Then add in the time to test, integrate and ship and you will have a ballpark figure.
The multiple all estimates by π and you'll have the perfect schedule. ;-)

Thank you very much I think this is a solid option

Multiply by pi made my day, ty :'D

As long as it is pi in the sky, you're onto a winner!

I generally prefer the "Scotty factor" of four, but π with sufficient decimal places has the useful property of creating a less deducible fudge factor that's harder to cut by fiat, which is almost inevitable when sponsors want to initiate a project without adequate decomposition.

Build a Phased Project Including Introspection and Baselining Activities

As a part of the project plan the stakeholders will produce the actual specifications of the product, my question then becomes how do I create an accurate work breakdown structure or project schedule for the implementation of the specifications and the project overall without knowing what the specifications are?

You don't. If you can't get sufficient planning details ahead of time, then you can put together a phased project with time and budget allocated to tasks such as:
Phase 1

Gathering specifications.
Analyzing specifications and decomposing them into WBS packages for a subsequent phase.
Build out the plan for Phase 2 based on the information you've gathered and analyzed.
Some form of project introspection to determine if the project should proceed to Phase 2 based on the information you then have.

A phased project is extremely common in situations where you know generally what is supposed to come out of the very end of the project (e.g. "build a new website" or "move to a new data center") but no one knows exactly what that will actually entail. So identify both the known-unknowns and unknown-unknowns, you have to build in information-gathering, analysis (including development or realignment of budget, scope, schedule, and resource baselines), inspect-and-adapt, and go or no-go inflection points within the initial project plan.
Why This is a Common (Anti-)Pattern and How to Communicate to Stakeholders
If you are asking about specifications, that means you aren't doing factory work where you're churning out additional widgets you already know how to make. That means you have a cone of uncertainty anyway, so even if you had some initial hand-wavey specifications you'd want to build in phases and add sufficient slack to do periodic re-evaluation anyway.
All projects require slack and fine-tuning to be successful. Poorly defined projects simply require a lot more of both. Make that clear as part of the plan, add the risks of having so many unknowns and a lack of defined specifications to the risk register you create during project initiation, and move on with your life.
As long as you have pointed out that a project with no specifications can't be planned with exactitude, all you can do is include gathering and refining those things explicitly within the project itself. It's a common issue in project management, and the project's sponsors fundamentally own that risk so long as you've done your due diligence in pointing that out during project initiation.
Consider Emergent Design, or Pad for Replanning
No large project can be fully specified up front. This is a myth, and the source of much pain for project managers who don't already know that and who fail to effectively communication that to stakeholders.
If you can use an iterative methodology where the how of the project deliverables are an emergent property, then do that instead. Otherwise, the lack of initial detail around scope, functional, and non-functional requirements will require continuous re-planning. That's why change requests, scope control, and rebaselining are relied on so heavily in traditional project management.
Experienced project managers build these activities into their projects even when doing waterfall-type projects, whether explicitly or implicitly, for exactly the reasons given above. You just have to plan for all the replanning, and set everyone's expectations—including your own!—accordingly.
